# How does moderation work during private beta?

Tags: support

How does SE moderation work during the private beta?  Is it just general network moderators, are users assigned, or is there a vote?

Comment: Same thing on LH: http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/who-are-the-moderators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no moderators in the community other than the SE staffers, at the moment.

Here's how and when Stack Exchange chooses the pro-tempore moderators for a new site, quoting from [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/):

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
>
> Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
>
> Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
>
> Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

For the time being, we are relying on SE staffers to take care of issues we can't take care of ourselves (responding to flags, for example).